# Run heroku java servlet application in local server

Tags: eclipse, heroku

I am new to heroku I am trying to create a embeddedTomcat project. From eclipse I created a blank heroku project and pushed the cloned project to it(from here:https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-embedded-tomcat) from some reason it won't works . here is my log :

Fetching repository, done.

```
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.6... done
-----> Installing settings.xml... done
-----> executing /app/tmp/cache/.maven/bin/mvn -B -Duser.home=/tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b -Dmaven.repo.local=/app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository -s /app/tmp/cache/.m2/settings.xml -DskipTests=true clean install
       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
       [INFO]                                                                         
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Building embeddedTomcatSample Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ embeddedTomcatSample ---
       [INFO] Deleting /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ embeddedTomcatSample ---
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/src/main/resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ embeddedTomcatSample ---
       [INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/classes
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ embeddedTomcatSample ---
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/src/test/resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ embeddedTomcatSample ---
       [INFO] No sources to compile
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2:test (default-test) @ embeddedTomcatSample ---
       [INFO] Tests are skipped.
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ embeddedTomcatSample ---
       [INFO] Building jar: /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/embeddedTomcatSample.jar
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- appassembler-maven-plugin:1.1.1:assemble (default) @ embeddedTomcatSample ---
       [INFO] Installing /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.34/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.34.jar to /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.34/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.34.jar
       [INFO] Installing /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/7.0.34/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.34.jar to /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/7.0.34/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.34.jar
       [INFO] Installing /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/7.0.34/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.34.jar to /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/7.0.34/tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.34.jar
       [INFO] Installing /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/3.7.2/ecj-3.7.2.jar to /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/repo/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/3.7.2/ecj-3.7.2.jar
       [INFO] Installing /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jasper/7.0.34/tomcat-jasper-7.0.34.jar to /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jasper/7.0.34/tomcat-jasper-7.0.34.jar
       [INFO] Installing /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/7.0.34/tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.34.jar to /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-servlet-api/7.0.34/tomcat-servlet-api-7.0.34.jar
       [INFO] Installing /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/7.0.34/tomcat-juli-7.0.34.jar to /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/7.0.34/tomcat-juli-7.0.34.jar
       [INFO] Installing /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-el-api/7.0.34/tomcat-el-api-7.0.34.jar to /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-el-api/7.0.34/tomcat-el-api-7.0.34.jar
       [INFO] Installing /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-api/7.0.34/tomcat-api-7.0.34.jar to /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-api/7.0.34/tomcat-api-7.0.34.jar
       [INFO] Installing /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/7.0.34/tomcat-util-7.0.34.jar to /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-util/7.0.34/tomcat-util-7.0.34.jar
       [INFO] Installing /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jasper-el/7.0.34/tomcat-jasper-el-7.0.34.jar to /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jasper-el/7.0.34/tomcat-jasper-el-7.0.34.jar
       [INFO] Installing /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jsp-api/7.0.34/tomcat-jsp-api-7.0.34.jar to /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/repo/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jsp-api/7.0.34/tomcat-jsp-api-7.0.34.jar
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/embeddedTomcatSample.jar to /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/repo/com/heroku/sample/embeddedTomcatSample/1.0-SNAPSHOT/embeddedTomcatSample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ embeddedTomcatSample ---
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/target/embeddedTomcatSample.jar to /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/heroku/sample/embeddedTomcatSample/1.0-SNAPSHOT/embeddedTomcatSample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_36ddec06-fd36-46c0-b185-a3c43756177b/pom.xml to /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/heroku/sample/embeddedTomcatSample/1.0-SNAPSHOT/embeddedTomcatSample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time: 4.620s
       [INFO] Finished at: Sun Dec 29 04:06:49 UTC 2013
       [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/647M
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web

-----> Compressing... done, 54.2MB
-----> Launching... done, v5
       http://cvstomcatservletjsp.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:cvstomcatservletjsp.git
   e4af189..4149b1d  master -> master
```

How can I tackle this situation ? I have one more question I can run the heroku spring project in local machine using web app runner but in tomcat app it won't works .

This won't helps eithere: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRfLHuhWO74. I think it out dated . embedded jetty works well but tomcat not I don't know why ..